# Get the address of the recipient for a threaded sms

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I have been searching how to fetch the recipient phone number for a threaded sms.

A threaded sms can contain multiple recipients and i must get all the contact numbers.

Can anyone pls help me.

Note : i need to fetch only for sent sms so multiple receivers is possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"content://sms/" is not officially documented and it's realisation is up to device manufacturer. there is no clean way of retrieving any sms-related info.

Comment: Even content://sms/ does not have fields pertaining to multiple recipients.Moreover i need in conversation view(in mean threaded).In content://sms/ has info about each sms.not the threaded.So i'm using content://mms-sms/